How to add new data in object of cbjects where new data comes from state variable in react which is also object
I am trying to add data in a object of object where new data comes from a state variable in react which is also a object . the code of following is as follow
 let userData = {
    harsh:{
        password:"harsh",
        email:"harsh@",
        mobile:999999999,
    },
    mehul:{
        password:"mehul",
        email:"mehul@",
        mobile:8888888888,
    },
    khushboo:{
        password:"khushboo",
        email:"khushobo@",
        mobile:7777777777,
    }
}

and i want to add data in this userData object
let handleReg = (usernames) => {
    console.log("in handle register");
    for(let i=0;i<usernames.length;i++) {
        if(regDetails.regUser == usernames[i]) {
            console.log("username already exists kindly use a different username or login");
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("trying to add data in userData");
    let ru = regDetails.regUser;
    console.log(ru);
    return {...userData,ru:{
    password:regDetails.regPass,
    email:regDetails.regEmail,
    mobile:regDetails.regMobile,
   }
}

}

and the data is coming from state variable regdetails
let [regDetails,setRegDetails] = useState({
    regUser:'',
    regPass:'',
    regEmail:'',
    regMobile:'',
});

I have written the code to add the data ,I have used the spread operator and tried to add data through that ,but I am not getting the data added in userData

As it stands this question is impossible to answer, because it's completely unclear how and in which way the parts you've shown interact. Please update the question so that it includes an MRE

let handleReg = (usernames) => {
    console.log("in handle register");
    for(let i=0;i<usernames.length;i++) {
        if(regDetails.regUser == usernames[i]) {
            console.log("username already exists kindly use a different username or login");
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("trying to add data in userData");
    let ru = regDetails.regUser;
    console.log(ru);
   userData = {...userData,[ru]:{ // you have to update the variable user data 
    password:regDetails.regPass,
    email:regDetails.regEmail,
    mobile:regDetails.regMobile,
   } /// 

  userdata[ru] = { // or you can use this
    password:regDetails.regPass,
    email:regDetails.regEmail,
    mobile:regDetails.regMobile}
}

}```

also no need to create ru variable, use directly  regDetails.regUser

